# Scraping multiple pages with bs4 Beautiful Soup - only scrapes the first page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

*** My code is for practice only!

I'm trying to scrape the names and teams that each player in FPL from their website https://www.premierleague.com/ and I got some problems with the code.

The problem is it's only getting the page with the '-1' in the end of the url, wihch I haven't even inculded in my pages list!

there isn't any logic with the pages - the basic url is https://www.premierleague.com/players?se=363&cl= while the number after the '=' seems to be random. so I created a list of the numbers and added it to the url with a for loop:

my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas

plplayers = []

pl_url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/players?se=363&cl='
pages_list = ['1', '2', '131', '34']
for page in pages_list:
    r = requests.get(pl_url + page)
    c = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(c, 'html.parser')
    player_names = soup.find_all('a', {'class': 'playerName'})



    for x in player_names:
        player_d = {}
        player_teams = []
        player_href = x.get('href')
        player_info_url = 'https://www.premierleague.com/' + player_href
        player_r = requests.get(player_info_url, headers=headers)
        player_c = player_r.content
        player_soup = BeautifulSoup(player_c, 'html.parser')
        team_tag = player_soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'team'})
        for team in team_tag:
            try:
                team_name = team.find('span', {'class': 'long'}).text
                if '(Loan)' in team_name:
                    team_name.replace('  (Loan) ', '')
                if team_name not in player_teams:
                    player_teams.append(team_name)
                player_d['NAME'] = x.text
                player_d['TEAMS'] = player_teams
            except:
                pass
        plplayers.append(player_d)


df = pandas.DataFrame(plplayers)
df.to_csv('plplayers.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would comment this but I'm new and don't have enough reputation this so I'll have to keep it in an answer.

It looks like when you made a request to store in `player_r` you specified a headers parameter but didn't actually make a headers variable.

If you replace `player_r = requests.get(player_info_url, headers=headers)`with `player_r = requests.get(player_info_url)` instead, your code should run perfectly. At least, it did on my machine.